# Angular 6 Http Response Error Interceptor retry request not working

Tags: angular, error-handling, angular6, angular-http-interceptors

I am using a refresh token in order to re-log users when their jwt token expired. To deal with the re-logging I created a middleware class.
The api server returns the error code 498 when the token is expired, and 401 when there is no token / invalid token / invalid refresh token.
The part that asks for a new token works perfectly (I can build a new request with the new token), however I do not understand why the new request response never come back. I thought that `return temp_next.handle(request);`would be enough ...

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
    import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

    import { AuthenticationService } from '../services/authentication.service';

    @Injectable()
    export class ErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
        constructor(private authenticationService: AuthenticationService) {}

        intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
            return next.handle(request).pipe(catchError(err => {
                if (err.status === 498) {
                    console.log('Token expired', request.headers.getAll('Authorization'));

                    const currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));

                    const temp_next = next;
                    this.authenticationService.tryRelog(currentUser.username, currentUser.refresh_token, (new_jwt) => {
                        console.log('We got a new token after logging in', new_jwt);
                        const temp_jwt = new_jwt;
                        request = request.clone({
                            setHeaders: {
                                Authorization: `${temp_jwt}`
                            }
                        });
                        console.log('Retrying the request with new token', request.headers.getAll('Authorization'));

                        return temp_next.handle(request);
                    });
                }
                if (err.status === 401) {
                    console.log('We are not authorized here');
                    // auto logout if 401 response returned from api
                    this.authenticationService.logout();
                    location.reload(false);
                }
                if (err.status === 200) {
                    console.log('OK');
                    return;
                }
                const error = err.error.message || err.statusText;
                return throwError(error);
            }));
        }
    }
```

Comment: The return doesn't return from the catchError callback (as you're doing when you return return throwError(error)). It returns from a callback function passed to tryRelog().

Comment: Yes you are right, but shouldn't it work without the return anyway, by just doing `temp_next.handle(request);` ?

Comment: No. That would create an observable that nobody subscribes to, since it's never returned.

Comment: Ah ok, so what is the best way to get around it then ? I tried to fake a subscribe by doing `temp_next.handle(request).subscribe()` but it does not work either.

Comment: The best way would be to refactor the AuthenticationService so that, instead of taking a callback as argument, it returns an observable. Once you have that, you can `return this.authenticationService.tryRelog(currentUser.username, currentUser.refresh_token).switchMap(new_jwt => { the code you have now in the callback }`